# pgadmin3 dark theme for Windows?

Tags: postgresql, themes, pgadmin

Is there a dark theme for pgadmin3 under Windows? I have been searching in the options and googling for a good bit trying to find anything that would point to it, to no avail.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only way you can have a dark background is

> File --> Options --> Query tool --> Colours

select a custom background and also change the font colour according to the background.
pgadmin [documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/options-query_tool.html)

Update:

In pgadmin4: `File --> Preferences --> Miscellaneous --> Themes`

Answer (score 114):

pgAdmin 4 v4+ has an inbuilt dark theme in it.

File --> Preferences --> Miscellaneous --> Themes

Select dark theme.

[image]

You can download the latest version of pgadmin [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/).

Once you install, it overwrites your old version. Goodluck

Comment: This answer is valid for pgAdmin 4 v5 as well